# node fs (filestream) creating 2 files when uploading single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using the following code to allow people to upload images to a server:

```
app.post("/api/upload", function (req, res) {

  fs.readFile(req.files[0].path, function (err, data) {
    console.log('The data for the file..', data);

    if (err) {
      res.send(err).end();
    } else {
      // ...
      var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/" + req.headers["account_id"] + '_' + moment().format('MM_DD_YYYY_HH-mm-ss') + '_' + req.files[0].originalname;
      fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
        console.log('File Written');
        if (err) {
          res.send(err).end();
        } else {  
          res.send({
            success: true,
            file: newPath,
            files: req.files
          }).end();
        }
        //res.end({"success": true})
      });
    }
  });


});
```

The problem is that for evey file that gets uploaded I am also getting a arrayBuffer version (I think) see image:

[image]

How can I prevent this, and most of all, why is it happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your file successfully uploading to target directory?

Comment: Also are you using multer or something else to help upload your files?

Comment: I am not using multer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are seeing the temporary upload file and your saved file. Your code should work just fine if you add in code to delete the temporary file (req.files[0].path).

Answer (score 1):

Working on sometime I got a solution using multer module.Using this module you can upload both files and images.And it successfully uploaded to the destination folder.

Here is my server code `app.js`

```
var express =r equire('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/uploads')//here you can place your destination path
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

app.get('/api/file',function(req,res){
res.render('index');
});
app.post('/api/file', function(req, res) {
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage}).single('userFile');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log("File uploaded");
        res.end('File is uploaded')
    })
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("working on port 3000");
});
```

Create a `views` folder and place this `index.ejs` file in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After this run the server as `node app.js`.Open the browser and type `http://localhost:3000/api/file` after runnig this url choose a file which you want to upload to destination folder.And have a successfull response in both terminal and browser.Hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use modules like `multer`, file uploads are typically (permanently) saved to disk (unless you change the underlying backing storage in `multer`'s case). So when you read the file and write it back out, you have a copy.

If you need to make a copy of a file, this is not the most efficient solution because you're reading the entire contents into memory. Until a more efficient copy mechanism is in place, you're better off doing a streaming copy (using `fs.createReadStream()` and `fs.createWriteStream()`) to minimize the amount of data in memory.

If you instead wanted to *move*/*rename* the file that `multer` saved to disk, then you can either configure `multer` such that you provide a destination filename dynamically (there is such a hook available), *or* you can use [`fs.rename()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) to move or rename the file afterwards.

Comment: Can you provide code? I simply want to upload the file from my API to a folder called uploads. That's it.